# Is the pip that comes with anaconda3 actually pip3?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have anaconda3 installed, and I found an executable file, pip, in anaconda3/bin/. I did not see any file named pip3 coming inside anaconda3. So is the this pip actually pip3? Is there any way that I can verify it explicitly?

Comment: Run `pip -V`, this will give you information about python path and version of python.

Answer (score 2):

Activate your conda env and then execute on terminal `pip --version` should indicate which python (2.x or 3.x) is using, that should clear out your doubt.